# Can the frequency of a flashing light be counted using a video camera

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, measure, opencv3.1

Is there a formula to determine that max flash rate countable by a video camera? I am thinking that any flash rate > # of fps is not practical. I get hung up on the fact that the shutter is open only a fraction of the amount of time required to produce a frame. 30fps is roughly 33.33ms. If the shutter is set for say 1/125 which is about 8ms or roughly 25% of the frame time. Does the shutter speed matter? I am thinking that unless they are sync'd the shutter could open at any point in the lamp flash ultimately making counting very difficult.

The application is just a general one. With today's high speed cameras (60fps or 120fps) can one reliably decide on the flash rate of a lamp. Think alarm panels, breathing monitors or heart rate monitors or the case of trying to determine duty cycle by visual means.

Comment: An issue is that the flashing light is possible flashing way faster than the fps of the camera. Is this a high speed camera? What is the source of the flashing light?

Comment: please explain your motivation. there are usually much cheaper and better solutions to that problem. you might indeed have some problems, depending on shutter times and flash duration.

Comment: Sorry. In my zeal for brevity I missed crucial information. I have edited the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is related to the sampling problem. 
You can refer your problem to the [Nyquist - Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)
Given a certain frequency of acquisition (# of FPS) you can be sure of your counting (in every case, no matter of syncronization) if

> "# of FPS" >= 2* flashing light frequency (in Hz)

Of course this is a general theoric rule, things can work in a quite different way (I am answering only regarding the number of FPS in a general case)

Comment: Thanks. It is a starting point. Ultimately, experimentation will be required I think.